# What's wrong of identify a subset in this way: bull[c(1:10) & bull$YearsPro >= 10,]?

Tags: r

I would like to identify a subset of a data frame called "bull".
The subset should contain any case which is one of the first 10 rows of the data frame, and has a value of the "YearsPro" variable no smaller than 10. So I wrote:

```
bull[c(1:10) & bull$YearsPro >= 10,]
```

But the above codes do not give the intended output. It also returns a warning message saying that "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

I was wondering what goes wrong with my codes. Thank you!

Here is the reproducible example:

```
bull <- structure(list(Rider = c("Joao Ricardo Vieira", "Matt Triplett", 
                     "J.B. Mauney", "Kaique Pacheco", "Nathan Schaper", "Valdiron de Oliveira", 
                     "Guilherme Marchi", "Silvano Alves", "Reese Cates", "J.W. Harris", 
                     "Stetson Lawrence", "Mike Lee", "Fabiano Vieira", "Cody Nance", 
                     "Ben Jones"), Country = c("BRA", "USA", "USA", "BRA", "USA", 
                                               "BRA", "BRA", "BRA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "BRA", "USA", 
                                               "AUS"), YearsPro = c(3L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 16L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 
                                                                    8L, 14L, 9L, 9L, 17L)), .Names = c("Rider", "Country", "YearsPro"
                                                                    ), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Create a new data frame of the subset. `df1 = bull[1:10, ]; df1[df1$YearsPro > 4, ]`

Comment: `bull[seq(nrow(bull)) <= 10 & bull$YearsPro >= 10, ]` perhaps

Comment: Thank you! Those codes work. I actually wanted to know why my codes are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the & operator is for boolean statements. Your first statement 'c(1:10)' is an indexing statement. You might try something like this:

```
new_bull <- bull[c(1:10),]
new_bull[new_bull$YearsPro > 10,]
```

OR

```
subset(bull[1:10,], YearsPro > 10)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It solved my confusion about where my codes went wrong.

Comment: But this is not working: subset(bull[1:10], YearsPro > 10)

Comment: @mooninnap missed a comma, edited and should be correct now

Answer (score 0):

To be honest your question it is not so clear, because you didn't return reproducible code with an extract of your dataset. 
Anyway, I suggest you two ways using tidyverse functions. It depends on which is your goal:

```
library(tidyverse)


set.seed(1234)
bull <- data.frame(
    id=c(1:20),
    YearsPro=sample(1:30,20,replace=TRUE)
)

# Top 10 rows with YearsPro>10
new_bull <- bull %>%
    top_n(n=10) %>% 
    filter(YearsPro>10)

# Into top 10 rows select records with YearsPro>10
new_bull1 <- bull %>%
    slice(1:10) %>% 
    filter(YearsPro>10)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I'm a newbie of R. Now I know I should have included a reproducible example.